# C# - Keeping the values from functions

Tags: c#, function, methods

I want to call a function like `Spawn()` in this case, but without losing values from it after calling it (for example, I want `entityPicture` to still be available after I call `Spawn()`, so I can use it later on `MainWindow_KeyDown()` function). Same with `X` and other variables like that.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace EpicGame
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Form
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int EntityCount = 0;
        Background.ImageLocation = "Background.jpg";
        Background.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;

        Spawn(600, 600, EntityCount, "Player 1.png"); EntityCount++;
    }

    // Controls
    public void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.D) MoveRight();
        entityPicture.Location = new Point(X, Y);
    }

    // Movement
    public void MoveRight()
    {
        X++;
    }

    // Entity spawning
    public void Spawn(int X, int Y, int ID, string Path)
    {
        PictureBox entityPicture = new PictureBox();
        Image Entity = Image.FromFile(Path);
        entityPicture.Image = Entity;
        entityPicture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
        entityPicture.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        entityPicture.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        Controls.Add(entityPicture);
        entityPicture.BringToFront();
    }

    private void Background_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it public in the form class like:

```
  public partial class MainWindow : Form
  {
      PictureBox entityPicture = new PictureBox();                                         

  }
```

I don't know the type of entityPicture so just used PictureBox as example, you use the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Your root issue is one of scope.  Have a look at this video, it walks through your exact issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NemPMKTxM7w

You can technically move `entityPicture` to the top of the class, however given this appears to be a WinForms window, I would add the `PictureBox` via the designer so it's only declared once.  If you declare it at the class level and reinitialize it in `Spawn` (i.e. `= new PictureBox()`) repeatedly, you're going to create a memory leak.